# Problema com impressão de elementos HTML na tela

Tags: css, html

Estou fazendo um *software* (*minigame*) que trabalha com um baralho. No painel administrativo do mesmo eu preciso visualizar e consultar o baralho do jogo. Eu realizo uma consulta na base de dados e, com os resultados retornados, imprimo na tela dentro de uma tag `ul` com várias tags `li`. Testei no Firefox, Safari, Chrome e Opera e acontece um problema.

Vejam a imagem de como o conteúdo é impresso na tela:
[image: Erro no front]

As cartas eram para sair todas como no primeiro bloco de cartas, mas não sei o que está acontecendo, pois ficam espaços vazios onde os mesmo eram pra ser preenchidos com cartas. Todas as cartas estão sendo devidamente retornadas pela consulta, só que estão ficando em lugares errados.

Tenho os código HTML/PHP abaixo. Faço uma consulta, que me retorna os valores corretos, mas fora do lugar como na imagem acima.

```php
<ul>
        <?php 
                $sql_Card = "select * from sv_cartas limit 0, 30";

                try{
                    $querySelectCard = $conecta->prepare($sql_Card);
                    $querySelectCard->execute();

                    $resultSelectCard = $querySelectCard->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                }catch(PDOException $erroSelectCard){
                    echo "Ocorreu um erro ao consultar as cartas";
                }

                foreach ($resultSelectCard as $resultCampos) {
                    $descricao = $resultCampos['cartaDesc'];
                    $cor = $resultCampos['cartaCor'];
                    $simbolo = $resultCampos['cartaSimbolo'];
                    $numero = $resultCampos['cartaNumero'];
                    $diretorio = $resultCampos['cartaDirectory'];

                    echo "<li>";
                        echo "<img src='../cartas/".$diretorio."' alt='".$descricao."' title='Número:".$numero.", Cor:".$cor.", Símbolo: ".$simbolo." '/>";
                        echo "<strong>Carta: </strong><span>".$descricao."</span>";
                    echo "</li>";
            }
        ?>
    </ul>
```

E meu CSS parece normal. Vejam:

```css
.pagcartas ul{list-style: none;
          display: block;
          font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
          float: left;
          padding: 5px 0 10px 8px;
          margin: 10px 0 0 12px;                 
          border: 1px solid #93AAB5;
          border-radius: 10px;
          background: #E7ECEF;
          width: 842px;
          }                        

.pagcartas ul li{background: #70909D;  
             padding: 2px 2px 5px 2px;
             float: left;
             border: 1px solid #ccc;
             margin: 5px 8px;
             border-radius: 10px;
             text-align: center;
             display: inline;
             } 

.pagcartas ul li img{border: 1px solid #ccc;
                 display: block;
                 border-top-left-radius: 5px;
                 border-top-right-radius: 5px;
                 width: 95px;
                 margin-bottom: 3px;
                 }                              

.pagcartas ul li strong{color: #fff}    

.pagcartas ul li span{color: #333}
```

Alguém já passou por algo parecido?

Comment: O que você quis dizer com fora do lugar qual era o resultado esperado? E por favor, edite o seu código incluído marcação de código para ficar mais fácil a leitura.

Comment: @Cleiton Como faço para marcar o codigo segundo a sua linguagem aqui no Stackoverflow?

Comment: @Luitame a marcação estava correta (para CSS), o que faltou foram 4 espaços em branco antes de cada código. Coloquei, e marquei também a parte de PHP, dá uma olhada no histórico de edição pra ver como é.

Comment: Obrigado @mgibsonbr! Eu falo gora do lugar por que são varios elementos 'li' impressos. Então todas as linhas abaixo eram pra ser impressas assim como o primeiro bloco de cartas. Mas só que não acontece assim. Ele simplesmente coloca deixa espaço vazios...

Comment: Sua pergunta não está clara. Você poderia postar o código HTML esperado, e o que está saindo, destacando sua intenção? (se é esse o problema)

Comment: Não consegui [reproduzir seu problema](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/Bnc7x/) no Chrome nem no Firefox... Qual browser você está usando? E, se tiver algo de diferente entre seu caso e o jsfiddle linkado, favor atualizar com os detalhes relevantes.

Comment: dei mais uma atualizada na pergunta olhem se agora dá pra me entender

Comment: Caro, tente postar o código HTML resultante do processamento da consulta.

Comment: O HTML é como esperado... Vem do jeito que é pra ser

Comment: @Luitame Eu continuo sem conseguir reproduzir o problema. Até [modifiquei o exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/Bnc7x/1/) para mudar os tamanhos da descrição, mas continua tudo normal (i.e. sem espaços em branco à esquerda). Tem algo errado, ou no resto do HTML da página, ou no resto do CSS. Experimente criar um jsfiddle com o conteúdo exato da sua página, de modo que a gente consiga ver o problema (o HTML gerado, como sugerido pelo @Calebe).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Desculpas pessoal por atormentar vocês com essa pergunta. Mas depois demorar mais de 1 hora e meia tentando ver o causador desse problema. Descobri que o motivo de estar acontecendo isso é culpa do design gráfico que fez o baralho as imagens são de tamanhos diferentes por isso estava desorganizado em espaços em branco pois uma era maior do que a outra. Consegui resolver isto, definindo o height para imagem e tudo rodou normal. :D

Código Alterado:

```css
.pagcartas ul{list-style: none;
          display: block;
          font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
          float: left;
          padding: 5px 0 10px 8px;
          margin: 10px 0 0 12px;                 
          border: 1px solid #93AAB5;
          border-radius: 10px;
          background: #E7ECEF;
          width: 842px;
          }                        

.pagcartas ul li{background: #70909D;  
             padding: 2px 2px 5px 2px;
             float: left;
             border: 1px solid #ccc;
             margin: 5px 8px;
             border-radius: 10px;
             text-align: center;
             display: inline;
             } 

.pagcartas ul li img{border: 1px solid #ccc;
                 display: block;
                 border-top-left-radius: 5px;
                 border-top-right-radius: 5px;
                 width: 95px;
                 height: 127px; /*Foi isso aqui que solucionou :P aff*/
                 margin-bottom: 3px;
                 }                              

.pagcartas ul li strong{color: #fff}    

.pagcartas ul li span{color: #333}
```

Olhem como ficou uma belezura... Hehehe
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora todas uma do lado da outra enfileiradas. Perfeito. :D

Comment: Hehe de fato, é sutil... Na sua imagem parecia que estava tudo da mesma altura, então nem me incomodei em testar. Se o tivesse feito, teria [visto o problema imediatamente...](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/Bnc7x/2/)

Comment: mas valeu pela força. Essas coisas acontecem principalmente com os juniors hehe! Abraços...

Comment: Ah ja tava animado pra responder logo que vi a pergunta, tinha ctz que era isso...hsuahsaush mais que bom que deu certo... xD

Comment: Hehe vlw @KennyRafael !!!